# Open Graph API - Action for our application keeps getting rejected for same reason

Tags: submit, facebook-opengraph

We are trying to use the Open graph API for our application and want to use the actions: User Messages and Tags.

We understand that we have to provide step by step instructions. And we have done that however we keep getting the following  message from Facebook: Your Ask action for Shopgodt needs to be updated.

The Error Message:

> User Messages (Needs Approval) - Allow users to write a personalized
>   message attached to this action.   Tags (Needs Approval) - Allow users
>   of my app to tag other users for this action.
>
> We are unable to test this action according to the usage instructions
>   provided. We could not find the "ask a question" section on your page.
>   Include all necessary passwords, test user credentials and links to
>   staging servers that we need to test your action. Test users cannot
>   like pages, so please don't place your app behind a like gate. If you
>   require spending money to trigger the action, please provide a free
>   fake product or a coupon for the test user to purchase. Once you have
>   made these changes, re-submit your action.
>   https://developers.facebook.com/docs/technical-guides/opengraph/video-tutorials/

These are the step by step instructions we have provided:

1. Go to http://wwww.shopgodt.com
2. Click on Facebook icon and enter these credentials username: XXXX Password: XXXX
3. Once you are successfully logged in Click on the "Ask a question" button highlighted by the red arrow in the snapshot below.(snapshot upload)
4. This will open a popup to ask the question
5. Click on any image (right hand side of the page) and then enter the question (as shown in step 3 image) in the "type your question here" box.

> This is where we require the USER MESSAGE action.

1. If you enter the name "XXXX" in the text box called "Type a friends name" it will show your list of friends, select the user you want to tag. (In this case there are only X friends.)

> This is where we require the TAGS action.

1. Click on "submit question"
2. Then go to the Facebook "news feed" and you should see the question and link on the feed.

We were very diligent on reading up about the OpenGRaph API, we have tried to be as detailed in our instructions.
We are just not sure why we are getting this error. This is the second submission we have done and are really perplexed as to why it is happening.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: you sure while submitting to facebook you wrote "www" instead of "wwww" as you have written in here.

Comment: off-topic, please see:  [Why can't I ask customer service-related questions?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/255746)

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about facebook approval

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the other users have pointed out, the URL to your site has a typo. Make sure you point to the correct site so Facebook can test.

Are you using a Facebook Test User created from your app? If not, check the App Settings page and click on Developer Roles. You'll be able to create a Test User from the last section on the page. You can provide Facebook with a Link that will automatically log them into the account.

You provide a screenshot for the "Ask a question" button (can you include it?). Is this button available to the user you provided login details for? Make sure you test the process with the user you provide to facebook.

Steps 3 and 5 give different instructions for the same thing. One says click an image and other says click the button. Which is it? Clarify this point and see if it makes a difference.

Finally, when testing your site, I noticed that you are not asking for the 'publish_actions' permission. This means that the action isn't actually published.

Fix the above issues and resubmit your action. Hopefully it will get approved next time around.

Comment: Hi Niraj THanks for the prompt response. I made a mistake on stackoverflow but did enter the correct URL in the system. I am going follow the steps you proposed and lets see if it works.

Comment: Wohooo! We got approved! Our mistake which was blatant was not creating the Facebook Test User.

Answer (score 1):

1. in your question above, you have written "wwww" instead of "www", hope you have written that correctly while submitting to facebook.
2. facebook is removing the custom actions starting feb 6th, 2013. check the corresponding doc here http://developers.facebook.com/roadmap/completed-changes/ . 
   it says

**End of custom actions for content consumption**

We will no longer show Custom Open Graph actions that were published simply by a user consuming content. If you own one of these actions and it was previously approved, you will have received an email from us. Developers should stop publishing these actions as doing so will return an error starting February 6th. The only actions that can be published upon a user simply consuming content are built-in actions.

Comment: Hi Smita, Thanks for pointing out (1) but I did put in the right link just not on stackoverflow. What exactly does "Custom Open Graph actions that were published simply by a user consuming content" mean? Our custom action enables the user to ask a question to a Facebook friend relating to an item purchased.